# What am I drilling into in my century building's exterior wall?

Tags: drywall, mounting

I am trying to mount a TV to a wall and am having a difficult time determining where the studs are and what I'm drilling into.

I live in a brownstone apartment and the wall is on the side of the neighboring building. The stud finder indicates there is something 1.5" deep in but the readings are inconsistent. I have carefully drilled into the places where the stud finder was able to find something and was met with a hard object for every hole (keep in mind, the holes are all a few inches away from one another). When I shined a light in the hole I see a white/beige kind of color but it's extremely hard and makes a crisp sound when the drill bit is tapped against it. I can't imagine wood sounding like that but I also can't imagine there is a stud every 2" away from one another. Now I'm thinking it's concrete but I'm unsure how to determine that unless I power through and keep drilling.

Will try to attach a decent picture of what the inside of the hole looks like but it's difficult to capture it clearly.

The TV weighs around 16lbs and the building was built around 1899. The wall mount is a swivel and weighs a little over 6lbs.

[image]

Comment: Guarantee you're not drilling a hole that size into concrete without a rotary hammer & diamond hole saw, so it's not concrete.

Comment: Studs should be 16 or 24 inches apart and have a brownest(light to dark) colour.  Depending on the stud finder, they might show sections of different density, not wood studs.  Do you have wood trim at the bottom/top that can be removed to make/cut bigger holes to find stud/what is behind the plaster/drywall layers?  Edit the size/weight of the TV into question.  Not usually recommended, but if the white stuff is solid, drywall anchors might do if TV is light enough, or to place plywood sheet on the wall.

Comment: The age of the building is probably relevant. CMU block has been a common firewall/sound break between condos for decades. You might have been able to dent that material with your drill.

Comment: How heavy is the TV, and are you installing it tight to the wall? Or do you have one of those swinging arm mounts that holds the TV at a non-trivial distance from the wall? If it's one of those swinging arm ones, then how far does it extend from the wall?

Comment: Have you asked neighbors and/or maintenance people?

Comment: @popham This was the answer! The building is over a hundred years old. What was confusing me was the strange look of the material I was encountering. I believe behind this sheet of drywall was paint over CMU. After I switched to a drill bit for cement, I was able to get through it.

Comment: If the wall is 120 years old, it could be actual cinder block. You might proof test your mount with 1.5 times the TV weight before hanging the TV. Sleeve anchors get some of the better performance from unreliable substrates if that becomes necessary.